# Why is the state of open null?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-props, react-state

I try to use a prop value to set a state but it keeps giving me null. The prop value has a valid
value (boolean).

This is the constructor of the child component:

```
constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            customUser: props.customUser,
            open: props.open
        })
    }
```

If I log the prop it will give the value true, as I want. But when this value is used to set the state in the constructor. It will return null here and not render:

```
render() {
        return (
here  --->    <Dialog open={this.state.open}>
                <DialogTitle>Account Delete</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete your account?</p>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {
                    }}>Yes</Button>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={() => {this.toggleDialog}}>No</Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        )
    }
```

I tried using a different named state to set the prop value to. But this didn't work either.

Comment: Use `this.state =` not `this.setState`

Comment: Hi @AndyRay this answer helped me out, thank you very much. This problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

As the response of Andy Ray said, I used setState instead of this.state. Replacing this fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it with `componentDitMount` (or `useEffect` with newer version).

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { open } = this.props;
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    customUser: this.props.customUser,
    open: open || false
  });
}
```

You can do it like this with `componentDidMount`.